# Is every holomorphic $L^p(\mathbb{D})$ function in $H^p$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $f\in H^p$ where $H^p$ denotes the Hardy space for $1\leq p<\infty$. That is, $f$ is a holomorphic function on the open unit disk, $\mathbb{D}$, such that
$$\sup_{0<r<1}\int_0^{2\pi}\vert f(re^{i\theta})\vert^pd\theta<\infty.$$
Does it follow then that $f\in L^p(D(0,1))$, i.e.
$$\int_{\mathbb{D}}\vert f(z)\vert^p dz<\infty?$$
I assume the answer ought to be no. If the integral in the above supremum equals $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r}}$, then the  supremum is infinite, but the below intgral is finite. But I cannot find a holomorphic function with this property.

Edit: I corrected my title. I meant to ask the following inclusion: Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function in $L^p(\mathbb{D})$. Then must $f\in H^p$?

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{D}}|f(z)|^p dz =\int_0^1r(\int_0^{2\pi}\vert f(re^{i\theta})\vert^p d\theta) dr \le M \int_0^1rdr$ so clearly the inclusion works so $f\in H^p$ implies $f\in L^p(D(0,1))$; what you are arguing is that the reverse inclusion doesn't work and that's true

Comment: @Conrad Oops, yes, I wrote the inclusion in my question the wrong way. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Conrad I corrected my title and added an edit to clarify. Do you know an example of a holomorphic $L^p(\mathbb{D})$ function which does not belong to $H^p$?

Comment: as usual it's easy to look in $L^2$ as a guide and the condition $f\in L^2(\mathbb D)$ is $\sum |a_n|^2/(2n+2)< \infty$ while for $H^2$ the condition is $\sum |a_n|^2 < \infty$ so just pick coefficients that satisfy first and not second eg $a_n=1/n, n \ge 1$

Comment: oops - should be $a_n =1/\sqrt n , n \ge 1$ and the function $(1-z)^{-1/2}$ has coefficients asymptotic to those by the binomial formula so for a $L^2$ counterexample pick $f(z)=(1-z)^{-1/2}$ and then for an $L^p$ counterexample take $g=f^{2/p}$ where you pick say the root such that $g(0)=1$

Comment: @Conrad Thank you! Where did you get these conditions on the coefficients?

Comment: in $L^2$ you can compute the integrals explicitly since $|f|^2=f \bar f$ and by orthogonality the mixed terms cancel; so the $H^2$ integrals are more or less $\sum |a_n|^2r^{2n}$ and letting $r \to 1$ you get the condition mentioned, while the $L^2$ integral is again more or less $\int_0^1 (\sum |a_n|^2r^{2n}) r dr$ (again integrate to to $\rho$ and then let $\rho \to 1$ etc